# Ruby regex that starts with ONLY one opening bracket

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a regex that checks for a pattern that starts with only 1 opening curly bracket and any number of closing brackets so:

```
"something{word_or_not}}}}}}}"  
#should return true.  

"something{{word_or_not}}}}}}}}"  
#should return false.
```

This is how far I've gotten `"\{\w*\}\}+"` except not that far since this returns `true` for the second example.

Answer (score 0):

This regex may suit:

```
str1 = "{word_or_not}}}}}}}"
str2 = "{{word_or_not}}}}}}}}"

str1.match?(/\A\{[^{]*?\}+\z/) #=> true
str2.match?(/\A\{[^{]*?\}+\z/) #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try](http://rubular.com/r/29KQKpNazQ) this regex:

```
(?<!{){\w*}+
```

This uses a negative lookbehind to assert that there is not a `{` before the first `{`.

Answer (score 0):

One might explicitly check for [negative lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
%w|{word_or_not}}}}}}} {{word_or_not}}}}}}}|.
  map(&/(?<!{){\w+}+/.method(:=~))
#⇒ [0, nil]
```